# Using $where to query dates in MongoDB behaving differently in different environments

Tags: mongodb, date, heroku

I'm using $where to query objects by month and date using code like the following to get UserInfo collections with a Birthdate of May 7:

```
db.UserInfo.find( function() {
  var d = new Date(this.Birthdate);
  return d.getDate() === 7 && d.getMonth() === 4;
});
```

This works perfectly locally, returning UserInfo objects with birthdates set to May 7th. However, this breaks remotely (Heroku+Mongolab) because I get back objects with Birthdate set to 1210222800000 for example, which is May 8th. Why is this happening and how can I get mongo to return the correct objects?

Comment: 2.4.2 locally and 2.2.4 remotely, would that cause a difference in the getDate method?

Comment: 2.2 and 2.4 use different Javascript engines (spidermonkey vs V8).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a time zone issue. I assume your dates are all supposed to be "midnight" on the day in question.  This one is 8 hours off.

```
# TZ=UTC date -d @1210222800000
Tue Jun  8 08:00:00 UTC 40320
```

Since JSON doesn't really have a Date type, you have to be really clear where the conversion happens. Best practice is that it's the app's responsibility to always convert to UTC before sending to the database. (And to strip off the time if you're trying to just store a date. Otherwise your date comparisons will be wrong.)

It's also best practice to run your database servers and application servers in the UTC time zone. (The app should convert to local time if desired. Usually per-user since users are often in different time zones.)